# Dropdown Menu Issues

Tags: html, css

I want to display two dropdown menu, but I've got some issues with it.

I can't get my second dropdown menu to work properly. The first works fine, but when I specify the second the block doesn't work/changes.

Is there a conflict with the CSS or the HTML ?

How can I handle it, so that the second dropdown menu is shown ?

```css
    body {
     margin: 0;
        padding: 0
    }

    /*first navigation menu*/
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
    }

    li {
        float: left;
    }

    li a, .dropbtn {
        display: inline-block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: red;
    }

    li.dropdown {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }
    /*end first navigation menu*/

    /*second navigation menu*/
    .nav2 ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: deepskyblue;
    }

    .nav2 li {
        float: left;
    }

    .nav2 li a, .dropbtn2 {
        display: inline-block;
        color: yellow;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .nav2 li a:hover, .dropdown2:hover .dropbtn2 {
        background-color: deeppink;
    }

    li.dropdown2 {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown2-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown2-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .dropdown2-content a:hover {background-color: deeppink}

    .dropdown2:hover .dropdown2-content {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
  <html>
    <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    &nbsp;
    <div class="nav2">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown2">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn2">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown2-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
    <p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: I've done some edit (add code snippet etc)

Comment: I'm looking into how to post the code here.

Comment: OK, thanks for helping!

Comment: I see drop downs under both menus, not sure what the problem is... Using Chrome

Comment: The OP would like both menus to have vertical menus, but the 2nd menu has a horizontal menu. Please take a look at my working answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, take a look at the working example below. All I've done is cleaned up your CSS code by separating "dropdown behavior" from the specific styles per dropdown. Your original CSS for the first dropdown was messing with your CSS for dropdown2.

```css
body {
     margin: 0;
        padding: 0
    }

    /*dropdown behavior*/
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
    }

    li {
        float: left;
    }

    li a, .dropbtn {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    li.dropdown {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }
    
    /*end dropdown behavior*/
    
    /*end first navigation menu*/

    /*first navigation menu*/

    li a, .dropbtn1 {
        color: white;
    }

    li a:hover, .dropdown1:hover .dropbtn1 {
        background-color: red;
    }

    li.dropdown1 {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown1-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

    /*end first navigation menu*/

    /*second navigation menu*/
    
    .nav2 ul {
        background-color: deepskyblue;
    }
    
    .nav2 li a, .dropbtn2 {
      color: yellow;
    }

    .nav2 li a:hover, .dropdown2:hover .dropbtn2 {
      background-color: deeppink;
    }

    .dropdown2-content a:hover {background-color: deeppink}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown dropdown1">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn dropbtn1">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content dropdown1-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    &nbsp;
    <div class="nav2">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown dropdown2">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn dropbtn2">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content dropdown2-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
    <p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This works the way I want it! I have a better understanding now of CSS conflicts and how to separate and use certain functions/behavior. :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hope, this will help you.

```
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0
    }

    /*first navigation menu*/
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
    }

    li {
        float: left;
    }

    li a, .dropbtn {
        display: inline-block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: red;
    }

    li.dropdown {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }
    /*end first navigation menu*/

    /*second navigation menu*/
    .nav2 ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: deepskyblue;
    }

    .nav2 li {
        float: left;
    }

    .nav2 li a, .dropbtn2 {
        display: inline-block;
        color: yellow;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .nav2 li a:hover, .dropdown2:hover .dropbtn2 {
        background-color: deeppink;
    }

    li.dropdown2 {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown2-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown2-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .dropdown2-content a:hover {background-color: deeppink}

    .dropdown2:hover .dropdown2-content {
        display: block;
    }
</style>

<html>
    <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown2</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    &nbsp;

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown2">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn2">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown2-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown2</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>


    <h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
    <p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This gives the same error. I've put the result of your (and mine) code here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FVNFU45LJJSM

Comment: Sorry. I m not sure what you want exact. Did you see my attached screen-shot? This is not the result?

Comment: No problem. I want the exact same thing as the top/first menu. Just different styling and content. In your screenshot the menu drops down horizontally, I want it vertically

Comment: Hi, Hope I found the issue. We need to remove the <div class="nav2"></div> tag from teh code. I have edited my code. Please take it and check it. Now, the dropdowns are displayed vertically. See this link (https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FVNFU45LJJSM)

Comment: last solution doesn't work either :'( I have found a working solution now: see answer above. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at using [select tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) instead. It's a pure HTML solution (although you can certainly style it with CSS if you'd like) and will probably be less buggy then trying to use `<div>` elements and CSS.

Example:

```
<select name="dropdown-1">
  <option value="1">Link 1</option>
  <option value="2">Link 2</option>
  <option value="3">Link 3</option>
</select>

<select name="dropdown-2">
  <option value="1">Link 1</option>
  <option value="2">Link 2</option>
  <option value="3">Link 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'll remember this solution. I don't know if this solves my CSS conflicts though, because styling is very important. thanks :-)

Comment: Sure, glad to help :) Just for the record, you can style `<select>` fields and `<option>` similar to how you'd style a div. Here's [some examples](https://freefrontend.com/css-select-boxes/).